# redirect to specific page with devise and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

*How do i redirect to a specific page on successful login and successful registration?*

I tried this in my routes file but it still redirects to user/login

```
namespace :user do
    root :to => "welcome#index"
end
```

tried the devise wiki how-tos but no success...

*edit*: using *devise 1.1.rc1* and *rails 3.0.5*

Comment: using devise 1.1.rc1 and rails 3.0.5

Comment: try devise 1.2.0 the last stable version

Answer (score 4):

You can override after_sign_in_path_for to redirect to specific location after sign_in using Devise.

Try this in your `application_controller.rb`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   dashboard_path
end
```

Where `dashboard_path` might be the path you want to redirect the user to after sign_in.

Comment: thanks, is this in the application.rb? not application controller?